# lapacke or clapack if programming in c/c++ in linux

Tags: fedora, lapack

My purpose of using LAPACK is to calculate the cholesky of a matrix. I am programming in C/C++ in Fedora, but I am confused over which lapack to install - LAPACK with lapacke or clapack?

Comment: Just a comment. There is no such language a C/C++. There is C and C++. They are not the same. Are you wanting to code in C or C++?

Answer (score 9):

The basic difference between the two is the need for a Fortran compiler.

CLAPACK is basically just the reference NETLIB LAPACK routines passed through the old f2c converter, allowing the library to be compiled with a C compiler.

LAPACKE is an attempt (started by Intel IIRC) to define a formal C language interface for Fortran LAPACK libraries. It has the advantage that it is LAPACK implementation independent and will hide toolchain specific C to Fortran interoperability so that the programmer doesn't have to worry about them. LAPACKE also has the distinct advantage of working correctly with the C99 complex intrinsic type.

I would not expect a major performance difference between the two (the choice of BLAS dictates most of that), but I would probably favor LAPACKE + the LAPACK and BLAS implmementation of choice, if I were to start from scratch today.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, talonmies. I am coding in a mixture of c and c++. I have been struggling in the installation of lapack. I have just installed Lapack 3.3.1 and Lapacke, but when i make lapack_testing, it complains '../../../lapack-3.3.1/lapack_LINUX.a(xerbla.o): In function `xerbla_':
/trunk/lapack/lapack-3.3.1/SRC/xerbla.f:40: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'                                                 Should I install Lapack 3.2.1 instead of 3.3.1?

Comment: [solved]. In the make.inc, I found out that i need to set LINKER=fortran, then make lapacke_testing runs without error. THanks@

Comment: That is telling you that you are not linking the fortran standard library. You might find it easier to use the fortran compiler to link, and add the C or/or C++ standard libraries to the list of libraries you need to link.

Comment: Additionally, clapack seems to be unmaintained: http://nicolas.limare.net/pro/notes/2014/10/31_cblas_clapack_lapacke/